# Is the sequence convergent in quadratic mean or in distributional sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

This is another problem I am not sure about:

Determine if the following sequence of functions on R :

$$f_n(x) =\frac{\sin [x \sqrt n + \log(n)]}{(1 + nx^2)^\frac13}$$

1. converges in quadratic mean?
2. converges in the sense of distributions?

I know that convergence in quadratic mean means that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n-f_{\infty}|^2=0$$

Where $f_{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$.

But I have troubles computing $f_\infty$, I get that:

if $x \ne 0$ then $f_{\infty}=0$

if $x=0$ then $f_{\infty}=$ not defined (since it must jump on the line between -1 and 1)

So my conclusion is that it does not converge in quadratic mean,(?)

What about in the distributional sense? help?

Comment: 1. it's okay for an $L^2$ function to jump. And it does not need to be defined everywhere! 2. Maybe it's easier to investigate if your sequence is or is not a Cauchy sequence in the $L^2$ norm. 3. With the jump of the limit function (think of the derivative of the heaviside funtion) one could guess that you find convergence of $f_n\to 2\delta_0$ in the sense of distributions, where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac measure.  But what did you try so far?

Comment: 1. so f_n is convergent almost everywhere, but that does not really imply convergens in quadratic mean as far as I know.
2. how do you mean?
3. yes you are right, shuld it be something like this:
associate the distribution T with f_n, then T(φ)=<φ*|f_n> and then, since inner Product is linear we get that w-lim <φ*|f_n>=<φ*|f_infinite> and here I just did not find what I should write instead of f_infinite

Comment: As you say the derivative of heavyside is 2δ,because from one side to the other it jumps by 2. but f_n in my case does not not in the same way? it does not really jump, it is like its moving on a line between -1 and 1, Is that the same as δ?

Comment: You should rather associate with $f_n$ the distribution $T_n$ and speak of convergence of distributions :) @1&2. pointwise convergence can imply $L^2$ or quadratic mean convergence if e.g. one can apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Can you estimate the integral of $|f_n-f_m|$ below? If so it can't converge to zero. On the other hand. the only possible "limit" is the zero function. However the integral does not go to zero (i at least hope so). Hence it can't converge to zero

Comment: hmm i'm sorry, no it is not the same. Then probably it is not a "dirac" measure in zero. Sorry for that. Does the integral of $|f_n|^2\to 0$? What is $s$?

Comment: well that integral is n0t so easy to compute.. and what about s? I dont see a "s" anywhere

Comment: it's a $1/3$ :). Could you estimate the quadratic integral from above or elow? You definitely don't want to calculate that integral. What you could try to show is that $L^p$ convergence always implies convergence in the distrbutional sense and the limit distribution is the limit $L^p$ function. ($p\geq 1$)

Comment: we have that |f_n|^2<=1/(1+nx^2)^(3/2) ?

Comment: there is a square missing and 3 and 2 are exchanged, but i think yes. We have $|\sin|\leq 1$ and then we should find the estimate?

Comment: so we have that |f_n|^2<=1/(1+nx^2)^(2/3), no Square missing I hope. Then the integral of this estimate is bigger than the one over f_n

Comment: Sorry, i can't follow you right now. We want to show that $f_n\to 0$ in quadratic mean. To his end we show that $|f_n|^2 \to 0$ in the integral sense (or $L^1$-norm). This is done exploiting the dominated convergence theorem for which we need a dominating integrable function which is $\min\{1,1/|x|^{4/3}\}$

Comment: yepp I got it now=) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the estimate of $f_n$:
Consider $|x|>1$ and for $n\geq 1$. Since $|\sin (anything)|\leq 1$ 
you find $$|f_n|^2\leq (1/(1+nx^2)^{1/3})^2\leq (1/(nx^2)^{1/3})^2\leq (1/x^{2/3})^2=x^{-4/3} $$.
For $|x|\leq 1$ we find $|f_n|\leq 1$. Now by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem the integral converges in quadratic mean to the a.e pointwise limit $f=0$. Showing that $L^2$ convergence implies ditributional convergence should yield the rest.

This is roughly done in the following way. Associate with the distributions $T_n$ and $T$ the integral $T_n(\varphi)=\int f_n \varphi$ and $T(\varphi)=\int 0 \varphi$.
Then
$$|(T_n-T )(\varphi)|^2= |\int f_n \varphi|^2\leq \int|\varphi|^2 \int |f_n|^2 \to 0$$

I hope this is clearer and that there are no mistakes in my reasoning